# Android How to read an asset from outside of main activity

Tags: android, assets

I need to be able to be able to call readAsset from outside of the main activity of my application.  I have heard people mention needing to pass the Context around, but the language has been very vague.  Can someone describe the steps necessary to add the ability to call readAsset to an existing class that is not the main activity?  Creating a public function in the main activity and having others call that will not work as the place I need to add readAsset to, is in a separate thread.

Comment: What is your apprehension to passing `Context` to classes that would depend on the functionality?

Comment: I have none, but I haven't found an example of what I need to do.  I imagine it is simple, but am only finding vague descriptions.  Say I have my main activity and some other class (in this case, in a separate thread).  What do need to add in the other class, such that my assets will be available to me there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class NonActivity {
    public void doStuff(Context c) {
        //read from assets
        c.getAssets();
        //use assets however
    }
}
```

Not sure what you're asking, but perhaps something like this?  Just add to the existing class, and use the context to retrieve the assets. In your activity call the method like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    NonActivity n = new NonActivity();
    n.doStuff(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I was asking for.  I will try this tonight.  Thanks!

Comment: This was it.  Thought it would be easy.

Comment: be careful with passing around your activity's context.  If you are passing the context to a thread that outlives the activity you could have a memory leak.

Comment: This actually does not make sense nor answers the original question. The right question should be asked "How to access assets/resources" without any context. Assume a properties file app.properties contains isLogEnabled. How do you access such global property without passing the context around to every class that logs something.

Comment: @MGDeveloper that's a completely different question, though.

Answer (score 2):

To read assets, you need a [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context), but you *don't* have to use an `Activity` as your `Context`; you can use the [`Application`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object instead.

[Android Context without being in an activity? And other activity-less programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441295/android-context-without-being-in-an-activity-and-other-activity-less-programmin)

```java
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    public MyApplication() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
         return instance;
    }
}
```

You'll need to add the `android:name` attribute to the `<application>` element in `AndroidManifest.xml` first:

```xml
 <application android:name="com.example.MyApplication" ... />
```

Now you can call `MyApplication.getInstance().getAssets()` statically from anywhere.

Alternately, you could use [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/) dependency injection to inject an `Application` directly into your object. (Injecting the `Application` context is a bit tricky. See [Dagger 2 injecting Android Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692501/dagger-2-injecting-android-context) and [this issue filed on the Danger github repo](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/832).)

Answer (score 0):

Note all file system accesses should be done off the main thread, so you shouldn't read them during onCreate(). Instead you should use another thread, such as provided by an AysncTask.