# Dagger 2 error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am working on implementing dagger 2 in my project. For this, i have written below lines of code:

```
@Inject
VideoControllerView mediaController;

@Module
public class PlayerModule {

    @Provides
    VideoControllerView providesVideoControllerView(Context context, VideoControllerView.Controlers cntrls) {
        return new VideoControllerView(context, cntrls);
    }
}


@Component(modules = PlayerModule.class)
public interface PlayerComponent {
    VideoControllerView getVideoControllerView();
}
```

But when i am trying to compile my app, i am getting below given error:

```
Error:(14, 25) error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
android.content.Context is injected at
com.multitv.multitvplayersdk.module.PlayerModule.providesVideoControllerView(context, …)
com.multitv.multitvplayersdk.controls.VideoControllerView is provided at
com.multitv.multitvplayersdk.component.PlayerComponent.getVideoControllerView()
```

I have looked around on how to resolve this issue but of no avail. Please help me.

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692501/dagger-2-injecting-android-context

Comment: Show the code, where you create `PlayerComponent`.

Comment: I will be able to find DaggerPlayerComponent only after compiling right. At this moment, studio is not even allowing me to compile

Answer (score 11):

Please try to understand the error.

`PlayerModule.providesVideoControllerView(context, …)` requires a context, but Dagger does not have access to any `Context` object, so it cannot pass in any `Context`. It thus creates the error, telling you that it can't find any `Context` and that you should add a way for it to do so.

> Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Hence...A `context` cannot be provided without a `@Provides`-annotated method.

---

Make sure that the component your `PlayerModule` is a part of has access to a context.

Either make it a subcomponent of your ApplicationComponent, add a Context to your `PlayerModule`, bind your Activity instance as a Context, etc

There's a lot of ways to do this, but in the end you require a method like the following in one of your modules:

```
@Provides Context provideContext() { return myContext; }
```

Once Dagger can find a `Context` the error will go away.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanke you

Answer (score 5):

you need module like:

```
@Module
public class ContextModule {

    private Context context;

    public ContextModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @UefaApplicationScope
    Context provideContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

and then method injection:

```
    @Provides
    @Inject
    VideoControllerView providesVideoControllerView(Context context, VideoControllerView.Controlers cntrls) {
        return new VideoControllerView(context, cntrls);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was trying to migrate a `DataModule.kt` class from an app module to a library module, and I just had to add this method in `DataModule.kt` after the migration to enable it to find the context:

```
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    ): Context {
        return context
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `@ApplicationContext` annotation to fix it:

```
@Inject
@ApplicationContext
lateinit var appContext: Context
```

Comment: You can also use this annotation on the constructor of the class, for example: `@ApplicationContext private val context: Context`