# How to get Context and Read from Assets folder in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Every answer on this question is incomplete, and I get a lot of errors when trying to use the code.

Example: [read file from assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets)

```
AssetManager am = MainActivity.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("book.txt");
```

I get errors:

1. Non-static method 'getAssets()' cannot be referenced from a static context
2. Cannot resolve Symbol "AssetManager", which Import do I need for this?
3. context.getAssets(); context is undefined, what context do I need? MainActivity?
   what function do I use to get the Context of MainActivity? What imports do I need to make this work?
4. Do I need to add something to Gradle files? And what?

Comment: Maybe helpful: [Android How to read an asset from outside of main activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4126387/295004) ,[What is the difference between Activity and Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6518206/295004) Generally avoid calling any Android APIs outside of a Application/Activity/Service class or method without taking into consideration the lifecycle.